# Haskell extension for function indentation syntax

Tags: haskell, syntax

Apologies for the vague question title; I could't figure out the right one.

A few years ago I ran into a page (on the Haskell Prime wiki, I guess) of a language extension proposal. Suppose a Haskell code like:

```
f1 (f2 v1 v2 v3) (f3 v4 v5 v6)
```

and let's say the `f2 v1 ...` part has long function names and value names, making the whole line a lot longer than desirable and harder to read. We would want to change it into

```
f1
    (f2 v1 v2 v3)
    (f3 v4 v5 v6)
```

which is more readable and would represent the structure a lot more clearly, i.e. what is argument for what. But then, if we have a more complex relation like

```
f1
    (f2 (f3 v1) (f4 v2) v3)
    (f5 v4)
    (f7 v5)
```

then it gets untidy very quickly and parentheses get out of control.

Ideally we could

```
f1
    f2
        f3 v1
        f4 v2
        v3
    f5 v4
    f7 v5
```

So the structure is clear for both human and machine. But since it was impossible with the Haskell standard, a bunch of smart guys came up with the idea of a language extension to allow a new operator. The operator looked like `$` but had a different associativity. Let's say it's called `$$`, then:

```
f1 $$
    f2 v1 v2 v3
    f3 v4 v5 v6
```

would be equivalent to `f1 (f2 v1 v2 v3) (f3 v4 v5 v6)` and

```
f1 $$
    f2 $$
        f3 v1
        f4 v2
        v3
    f5 v4
    f7 v5
```

would translate to `f1 (f2 (f3 v1) (f4 v2) v3) (f5 v4) (f7 v5)`.

I'd love to use a GHC extension for this feature because implementing a DSL with a tree-like structure would be a breeze with it, but I couldn't locate any resource at all.

1. What is this concept (and the operator I called `$$`) called?
2. Is there already a GHC extension for this?

   - If there isn't, I'd really appreciate links to any other related extension. I am willing to learn how to write a GHC extension to implement this.

**Edit**: I know there are many workarounds, including Template Haskell QQ and parentheses, but I remember seeing a language extension proposal and my question is about that extension, not about the other ways of addressing the problem.

By the way, I feel very reluctant to consider parentheses an option, because parenthesizing a complex nested structure will make it look very cluttered and defeat the whole point of indent-based code layout. The benefit of "off-side rule" syntax over "curly brackets" syntax is compromised if you have to parenthesize just about everything and manually style it to look structured. I am pretty sure there are many Haskellers who consider it unclean, as observed in monoid-based libraries having a meaningless instance of monad (and an empty value to pass around) to exploit the `do` syntax. While they can write

```
example = mappend
    [ lorem ipsum
    , dolor amet
    ]
```

they prefer to declare a monad instance and write

```
example = do
    lorem ipsum
    dolor amet
```

not because it makes more sense type-wise but because it just looks clean and concise. (In fact the issue is worse with parentheses than with brackets because you need to insert almost twice as many special characters to represent the structure of function application.) It would also drastically reduce the chance of missing symbols by mistake, which is exactly the advantage of off-side rule languages over curly bracket languages. In the best scenario, missing or misplacing parentheses, brackets, or commas will result in a compile-time error and worst, a faulty program that does something wild and unintended.

Comment: It is unclear why both an extension and an operator are needed.

Comment: You need both an extension and an operator because otherwise you won't be able to add a new-style code into an existing old-style code. If there is no new operator, enabling the extension will make `a\n\tb c` always mean `a (b c)` and never `a b c`.

Comment: Why not just indent it like your fourth code snippet but keep the parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to find the page so I'll answer my own question.

It's called [Application Layout](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ExtendedLayouts#ApplicationLayout). It was proposed after the monoid layout, which suggests a new keyword `be` (or `mdo`) that would eliminate the need of meaningless monad instances to get the `do` notation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to embed your custom syntax in GHC Haskell, you could try [Quasiquoters](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation).

Shamelessly copying from the linked examples, quasiquoting can turn syntax like

```
[expr|1 + 3|]
```

into

```
BinopExpr AddOp (IntExpr 1) (IntExpr 3)
```

where

```
data Expr  =  IntExpr Integer
           |  AntiIntExpr String
           |  BinopExpr BinOp Expr Expr
           |  AntiExpr String
data BinOp  =  AddOp |  SubOp |  MulOp |  DivOp
```

You do need to build your own parser turning strings such as "1 + 3" into the actual term representation. In your case, you will need to deal with indentation on your own.

Comment: Thanks. I knew QQ was able to deal with this issue, but I am certain that there was a language extension proposal for this, and want to find it.